# spamassassin - filtering specific Cyrillic/Russian UTF-8 letters (base64 encoded)

Tags: email, encoding, unicode, spam-prevention, spamassassin

I am having some trouble setting up my personal `spamassassin` rules. My problem: I get a lot of Russian spam with Cyrillic letters, many in `UTF-8`. Because of that, searching for a charset is not sufficient. So I want to search a few typical Russian letters instead (e.g.): `(д|ж|з|и|й)`.

I tried the pattern `/(д|ж|з|и|й)/i` as well as `/(\xd0\xb4|\xd0\xb6|\xd0\xb7|\xd0\xb8|\xd0\xb9)/i` (these regex patterns should do the same, right?) in a `Subject` search:

```
header CYRILLIC_LETTER_PRESENT Subject =~/(д|ж|з|и|й)/i
```

Result: The `UTF-8` spam is still coming through. I analyzed the emails coming through. All of them have a similar structure. The (important part of the) source looks for one example spam mail as following

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0KLQtdCx0LUg0L/QvtC90YDQsNCy0LjRgtGM0YHRjyEg0J/QvtC60LDQt9GL?=  =?UTF-8?B?0LLQsNGOINC+0YLQu9C40YfQvdGL0Lkg0LLQsNGA0LjQsNC90YIg0L/QvtC7?=  =?UTF-8?B?0YPRh9C10L3QuNGPINC00L7RhdC+0LTQsCEg0J/RgNC+0YHRgtC+0Lkg0Lgg?=  =?UTF-8?B?0YDQtdC30YPQu9GM0YLQsNGC0LjQstC90YvQueKAiyE=?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 8 Mar 2017 06:57:11 +0100
From: =?UTF-8?B?0KDQsNC00LjQuSDQn9C40YjRgg==?= <radiypisht140@zarabotokfm8.ru>
Sender: radiypisht140@zarabotokfm8.ru
Message-ID: <904499458.39893@zarabotokfm8.ru>
X-Priority: 3
List-Unsubscribe: <http://ie8qrshyns.zarabotokfm8.ru/uns/tFRyGZzisv/58dhKEk2im53c/DBetz>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="291e4fd846a7aa548d279e9eb1f199e9_1"

--291e4fd846a7aa548d279e9eb1f199e9_1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

....encoded....body....

--291e4fd846a7aa548d279e9eb1f199e9_1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

....2nd(?)....encoded....body....

--291e4fd846a7aa548d279e9eb1f199e9_1--
```

I googled and found just one kind of useful information: http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/decoding-email-headers.html

So, this `subject` uses `RFC2047`: `=?UTF-8?B?msg_subject?=  =?UTF-8?B?msg_subject2?= [...]`. This line says us, the `subject` uses the `utf-8` charset and `base64` encoding (compare http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt).

Obviously, `spamassassin` is not decoding this (properly). I have not found any possibility to get this working. I found this site as well: https://dropbear.xyz/2007/08/07/filtering-base64-encoded-spam/

But this is not helping me, as it just describes, how to filter base64 encoded strings, that are long enough. Since I am looking for single characters, I cannot use this approach.

Am I missing something? Thanks for your help!

**edit:** I also tried the `rawbody` search, because this should decode the base64 encoding as stated in the [docs](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html):

```
rawbody CYRILLIC_LETTER_PRESENT /(д|ж|з|и|й)/i
```

Did not work for me as well, although it should search the whole body as well, and it is full of Cyrillic letters.

**edit2:** I tried to investigate the problem further. If I try to test textcat with `spamassassin -D textcat -t spamtest`, it tells me that it "`can't determine language uniquely enough`".

Moreover, I get the following result in the end:

```
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: *******
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=7.3 required=3.0 tests=HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST,
        HTML_MESSAGE,LOCAL_CYRILLIC,RDNS_NONE,SPF_SOFTFAIL,T_DKIM_INVALID
        autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
```

So it looks like it works. Everything were fine. My rule, here called `LOCAL_CYRILLIC`, works as intended. BUT, the problem is, this mail went through without being recognized as spam, as the same rule was present in the config file. I tried to forward the same mail again to me, and then, the email source looks like this:

```
X-Spam-Level: **
X-Spam-Status: No, score=2.7 required=3.0 tests=LOCAL_CYRILLIC,
    RCVD_IN_DNSWL_MED autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
```

So, there seems to be a difference between running that test locally on a file and an actually incoming email. Why? I always restart spamassassin with `systemctl restart spamassassin`. I checked it with `systemctl status spamassassin` and everything looks fine, `spamd` is restarted as well, as it should be. There I can find also the following info for the forwarded email:

```
spamd: clean message (2.7/3.0) for spamd:5555 in 6.0 seconds, 8371 bytes.
spamd: result: . 2 - LOCAL_CYRILLIC,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_MED scantime=6.0,size=8371,user=spamd,uid=5555,required_score=3.0,[...]
```

Comment: Have you tried to configure `ok_locales`? https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.2.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html#language_options

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip the `ok_locales`  just searches for typical regional charsets. This won't help me, as the emails are in `utf-8` =/

Comment: Sorry, `ok_languages` is more appropriate.  `UNWANTED_LANGUAGE_BODY` test score is 2.8 . https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Plugin_TextCat.html

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Maybe you are right, but still this is not working for my case, I tried it out as well, should have written this maybe. The emails are still coming through, with this option set. I guess it is because of their `utf-8` charsets in conjunction with `base64` encoding.

Comment: Have you tried to check texcat plugin work? `spamassassin -D textcat -t spam_message_file`

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip see new edit. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: is the rule being constructed using UTF-8? Those glyphs can be got using different code pages, no?

Comment: @Yorik I am not sure what you want to ask here. The configuration file itself is in `utf-8` charset. I think the unicode codes are unique for these letters.

Comment: I was having a similar situation. After saving the configuration file as UTF-8 it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, spamassassin is not decoding this (properly). I have not
>   found any possibility to get this working

It works for me with `Ubuntu 14.04`, `spamassassin 3.4`, `Perl 5.18.2`, locale: `fr_FR.UTF-8`.

Rule in `~/.spamassassin/user_prefs`:

```
header RUSSIAN_CHARS        Subject =~ /(д|ж|з|и|й)/i
describe RUSSIAN_CHARS      Russian characters in header
score    RUSSIAN_CHARS      10
```

When taking a mailfile and replacing the raw **Subject** line by the one in your question:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0KLQtdCx0LUg0L/QvtC90YDQsNCy0LjRgtGM0YHRjyEg0J/QvtC60LDQt9GL?=  =?UTF-8?B?0LLQsNGOINC+0YLQu9C40YfQvdGL0Lkg0LLQsNGA0LjQsNC90YIg0L/QvtC7?=  =?UTF-8?B?0YPRh9C10L3QuNGPINC00L7RhdC+0LTQsCEg0J/RgNC+0YHRgtC+0Lkg0Lgg?=  =?UTF-8?B?0YDQtdC30YPQu9GM0YLQsNGC0LjQstC90YvQueKAiyE=?=
```

Result:

```
$ spamc -R < mailtest
10.0/5.0
Spam detection software, running on the system  **redacted** ...

Content preview:  **redacted** [...]

Content analysis details:   (10.0 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
  10 RUSSIAN_CHARS          Russian characters in header
 0.0 DKIM_ADSP_CUSTOM_MED   No valid author signature, adsp_override is
                            CUSTOM_MED
 0.0 FREEMAIL_FROM          Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail provider
                            (**redacted**[at]gmail.com)
-0.0 NO_RELAYS              Informational: message was not relayed via SMTP
```

It also hits with `rawbody RUSSIAN_CHARS        /(д|ж|з|и|й)/i`

Comment: Lucky you, I did not have that much luck. Anyway, see new edit for additional info.

Comment: @nox: If I understand correctly, the filtering does work for you too. Now you have a different question which is why certain other rules match or not depending on how spamassassin is called.

Comment: Maybe this was my question from the very beginning. To clarify: I want to apply this rule for incoming emails (of course), and this rule is not working, whereas others are working perfectly there. However and whyever, my set up filter works locally indeed.